# Add Search bar on static website

Tags: javascript, searchbar

I add this code to my static website to show search result. Now search result is showing from google.

But I want to show result from my website content.

```
<gcse:search></gcse:search>

(function() {
  var cx = '017961058070984628774:iepfux5aokw'; // Insert your own Custom Search engine ID here
  var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
  gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
      '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
```

Comment: Can anyone help me to solve this please?

Comment: https://kb.iu.edu/d/bckj check this

Comment: Can't apply it. I use like this but not working. <gcse:searchbox-only resultsUrl="http://emoncmt2.byethost15.com/Digital"></gcse:searchbox-only>

Comment: Have you set up a "search engine" here: https://cse.google.com/cse/all and typed your site domain name and set it to only show results from that domain?